# What is the meaning of the subquery used in the order by clause of an SQL statement?

Tags: sql, subquery

What is the meaning of the subquery used in the order by clause of an SQL statement?

```
CREATE TABLE sales 
(
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    amount INT
);

COMMIT;

INSERT INTO sales 
VALUES (1, 'John', 100),
       (2, 'Mary', 200),
       (3, 'Tom', 300),
       (4, 'Jane', 150),
       (5, 'Peter', 250);

SELECT AVG(amount) FROM sales;

SELECT * 
FROM sales
ORDER BY (SELECT AVG(amount) FROM sales);
```

[image: The query result is..]

Comment: The subquery makes no sense here. The average amount of sales is one number. It makes no sense to order rows of a table, but use the same sortkey for every row. No sorting will take place.

Comment: How are you stuck? Now you are just asking us to rewrite the manual & duplicate Q&A on how aggregation works. [ask] [Help] [mre] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

A subquery in an `ORDER BY` clause can make sense, but it must be correlated then, i.e. the subquery would have to refer to a row of the table that is to be sorted. If we wanted to have the persons with the lowest average amount first, we could write:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales
ORDER BY (SELECT AVG(s.amount) FROM sales s WHERE s.name = sales.name),
         name,
         sales_date;
```

for instance.

In your example, the subquery is *not* correlated. The average amount of sales is one number. You tell the DBMS to order the rows, but use that same number as a sortkey for every row. No sorting will take place.